# Hidden fields in a grid won't import to a edit form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a grid that only displays one piece of information such as a title. Other fields are hidden. When you click edit a modal popup displays a form and imports the information from the grid for editing. The information in hidden field are not imported though. I don't want to display all the information in the grid because I have only room for the title.

How can I make this work? Thanks. Risho

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvForum" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsForumApproval" DataKeyNames="id" Width="200px"
RepeatColumns="1" DataKeyField="id" CssClass="gridview"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="_OnCommand">
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altbgcolor"  />
<Columns>                            
    <asp:BoundField DataField="title" />

    <asp:TemplateField >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfId" Value='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>                                
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfDesc" Value='<%# Eval("description") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>                                
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" Text="Approve" runat="server" onclick="lnkbtn_Click"/>
        </ItemTemplate>                                
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

```
protected void lnkbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    LinkButton btndetails = sender as LinkButton;

    GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)btndetails.NamingContainer;

    lblID.Value = gvrow.Cells[1].Text;

    txtTitle.Text = gvrow.Cells[0].Text;

    lblMessage.Text = gvrow.Cells[3].Text;

    this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cell-Text is empty if you are using `TemplateFields` with nested controls . You need to get the reference to the controls and use their appropriate properties(like `TextBox.Text` or `HiddenField.Value`). Therefor you can use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) on the `GridViewRow`:

```
var hfId = (HiddenField)gvrow.FindControl("hfId");
var hfDesc = (HiddenField)gvrow.FindControl("hfDesc");
txtTitle.Text = gvrow.Cells[0].Text;
lblID.Value = hfId.Value;
txtTitle.Text = hfdesc.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I knew I could count on you! :)